# Use the method is_vowel

Tags: python

Write a value returning method, is vowel that returns true if a given characters is vowel otherwise returns false. Write a program that prompts the user to input a sequence of characters and outputs the number of vowels. Please help me to run this problem and what is the exact code

Comment: What about giving it a try yourself first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `char in "aeiouAEIOU"` to determine if a character is a vowel, and use a `list comprehension` to produce a list containing only vowels, and find the number of vowels in the input string by finding the length of this list.

```
string=raw_input()
numOfVowels=len([char for char in string if char in "aeiouAEIOU"])
print(numOfVowels)
```

Input:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

make a list of vowel letter to comapre letters in input that user enters:

```
vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
user_ask = input("enter a string to count the vowel:\t").casefold()
```

by using casefold method, you do not need to worry about upper and lowercase letters.

```
count = 0
new_vowel = []
for i in user_ask:
    if i  in vowel:
            count += 1
            new_vowel.append(i)
print("number of vowels\n", count)
```

you can use counter if you want to print them in a key value pairs, i.e. as a dictionary.

```
from collections import Counter
dict(Counter(new_vowel))
```

Output

```
enter a string to count the vowel:  I am trying to learn
number of vowels :
6
```

and the dictionary form is:

```
{'i': 2, 'a': 2, 'o': 1, 'e': 1}
```